Probability Question: Determining Absence of Red Balls in a Partially Sampled Hat
I have a hat A with 1845 balls, in which 16 balls are red.
Then I have many other hats available with the same amount of balls.
If within these hats I find red balls, it means this hat is the same as hat A.
Then, I take one hat among them (hatB), but I can only sample it partially and extract 1086 balls from this.
Among the 1086, 0 were red. But maybe if I got all the balls, I would then extract red balls, nobody knows.
How can I calculate the probability that I did not sample by chance any red balls by sampling 59% of the total balls ?
In other words, what is the probability that this hatB indeed does not contain any red balls at all?
Thanks very much for your help.
So far I tried :


"Then I have many other hats available with the same amount of balls." Can these hats contain red balls as well?

The sampling from hatB is unclear. Is it supposed to have red balls in it? How many? How is the information about hatA helpfull, is hatB with a certain probability similar to hatA?

Consider reading about 'type I error' and 'posterior probability'.

I don't know if hatB is supposed to have red balls, but it could, that's all the dilemma, I want to calculate the probability that it does not given that I could not sample all the balls.

This is a fairly frequently asked question (if I wasnt on my phone I'd look for links to duplicates). Imagine the hardest case.... that there's exactly 1 red ball. If you randomly sample 59% of the total content, there's a 59% chance that the sample contains the red ball). [The question as currently  stated would require an assumption about the distribution of number of red balls.]

Asking the question a different way:

What is the probability that, sampling from hat A with $1845$ balls of which $16$ are red, none of the $1086$ samples are red?

then the answer would be:

sampling with replacement: $$\left(\dfrac{1845-16}{1845}\right)^{1086} \approx 7.8 \times 10^{-5}$$
sampling without replacement: $$\dfrac{(1845-16)!\, (1845-1086)!}{(1845-16-1086)!\, 1845!}\approx 6.1 \times 10^{-7}$$

so unlikely in either case and more unlikely without replacement.

Hello thank you very much, I added what I tried before you sent your respons, could you have a look and tell me if it also works please ?

Yes. The $\frac{{16 \choose 0}{1829 \choose 1086}}{1845 \choose 1086}$ which you later added to your question is the same as the $\frac{(1845-16)!, (1845-1086)!}{(1845-16-1086)!, 1845!}$ without replacement expression in my answer.

OK perfect, thank you very much for your time
